# pass ownership in a nested loop

Tags: loops, rust, ownership

I am trying to implement a sieve of eratosthenes, this finds all pirmes below n by creating an array, iterating through that array and whenever a prime is found marking off all multiples of that prime as non-prime.

My code for the marking step is:

```rust
for (index, val) in is_prime[3..marking_lim].iter_mut().step_by(2).enumerate() {     // borrow of is_prime
    if *val == true {
       primes_found.push(index as i32);           // add the prime to the list
       n_found += 1;                               // counter for primes found, cannot be exceeded in this step
       for val_2 in is_prime[index..(up_to_nth as usize)].iter_mut().step_by(index) {   // second borrow of is_prime
            *val_2 = false;
        }
    }
}
```

However, this doesn't work as the inner loop takes a mutable borrow of `is_prime` while it's still borrowed by the outer loop. Therefore, I need to somehow transfer ownership of the borrow to the inner loop so it can mark of the multiples. How can I do that?

Comment: Why do you need a mutable iterator?

Comment: Instead of iterating over the values in `is_prime` in the outer loop, you could just iterate over the indices (`for index in (3..marking_lim).step_by(2)`) and borrow `is_prime` only when needed by retrieving `val` via the index (`is_prime[index]`). Then you will be free to mutably borrow `is_prime` in the inner loop.

Comment: @AspectOfTheNoob because I'm modifying the values. see the line `*val_2 = false`

Comment: @Pioneer_11 But you don't modify `val` from the outer loop.

Comment: @ChayimFriedman yes. However, because of rust's "many immutable or one mutable" system of borrowing it is not possible to turn an immutable reference into a mutable reference. However, it is possible to pass ownership of a mutable reference from one variable to another `fn main() {
    let mut test_arr = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10];
    
    let a = &test_arr;
    let b = &mut a;
}` <-- invalid, does not compile `fn main() {
    let mut test_arr = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10];

    let a = &mut test_arr;
    let b = a;

    b[2] += 10;
    println!("{:?}", b)
}` <- compiles

Comment: I don't understand how that is related. Why can't you use `iter()` for the outer loop?

Comment: @ChayimFriedman because then it would be immutably borrowed in the outer loop, the inner loop cannot then mutably borrow the same data. It doesn't work at the moment but as I said in the question I'm looking for a way to transfer ownership of the outer borrow to the inner borrow which seems to me to be the only solution. If that can be accomplished then the inner loop will need a mutable reference thus if I'm transferring ownership of the reference in the outer loop then that reference needs to be mutable

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not possible to do exactly what you're asking. The easiest solution is to avoid borrowing `is_prime` in the outer loop:

```rust
for (index, index_2) in (3..marking_lim).step_by(2).enumerate() {
    if is_prime[index_2] {
        // ...
```

A fancier solution is to use `std::cell::Cell`, which lets you mutate the array items through a non-`mut` reference:

```rust
use std::cell::Cell;

let is_prime = Cell::from_mut(&mut is_prime[..]).as_slice_of_cells();

for (index, val) in is_prime[3..marking_lim].iter().step_by(2).enumerate() {
    if val.get() {
        primes_found.push(index as i32);
        n_found += 1;
        for val_2 in is_prime[index..(up_to_nth as usize)].iter().step_by(index) {
            val_2.set(false);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I'm guessing cell is some kind of reference counted container?

Comment: It's not reference counted; it's a zero cost wrapper. The tradeoffs are 1. It's not thread safe. 2. A shared cell prevents you from getting any reference directly to its contents (given a `&Cell<T>`, you can't get a `&T` or `&mut T`). This is why I have to use the cell's `get()` and `set()` methods in the code, with `get()` copying the value out of the cell instead of returning a reference.